# Migrating from Tomcat 6.0 to WebSphere 8.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, websphere

While deploying WAR file to websphere application server I am getting following error:

```
1. The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application Server.
 2. org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I understand there are some issues with my current web.xml but how could I find the issues before fixing it.

```
Note: Exporting the WAR file from Eclipse
```

Comment: Hmmm. You're exporting a `WAR` file from eclipse, however the error you're getting implies that you're trying to install an `EAR`. Obviously that won't work, as WebSphere seems to be expecting an `EAR` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bad DeploymentDescriptorLoadException message means that you likely have something wrong with your web.xml.  Check PROFILE_HOME/logs/SERVER/SystemOut.log (if deploying from the console) or PROFILE_HOME/logs/wsadmin.traceout (if deploying from wsadmin).  One of those logs should have an exception stack trace with some "Caused by" that contain the real problem.